# Displaying Media in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe

I'm trying to figure out the best solution for embedding/displaying various types of "media" in a custom Lightning Component. The media could be various file types but would typically be video or images. The media itself is accessed through a public URL, as the media file is stored outside of Salesforce in a variety of systems. An object has been created so that each "media" file has it's own record in Salesforce, with a field for the URL. This object is a child of the parent Account object. The ultimate goal is to then display the related "media" in a custom Lightning Component on the Account lightning record detail page. I've started by passing the URL from the field value into an `iframe` but obviously, this has its issues.

Is there a better way to go about displaying this "media" in a custom Lightning Component? If not, are there any tricks for improving the responsiveness of an `iframe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should figure out what [MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) you will be displaying. Based on the MIME Type use the correct output feature.

There are a ton of built in HTML5 tags to use for displaying different types of media. Here are some common ones:

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_reference.asp